# Add arguments in a virtual getter

Tags: node.js, virtual, mongoose

What I'm trying to do is something like that :

```
Schema
.virtual('getSomething')
.get(function(what) {
    if (!what) {
        return this.somethingElse
    } else {
        return this.something[what]
    }
})
```

The problem is that we can't pass arguments in a virtual getter, how can I achieve something like that without having to duplicate my code ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add it as an [instance method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods) instead of a virtual getter.

```
schema.methods.getSomething = function(what) {
    if (!what) {
        return this.somethingElse
    } else {
        return this.something[what]
    }
};
```

Comment: Indeed it's not replacement to virtual props, they are quite different [virtual props persist in model, but prototype methods doesn't get passed to requester], but OP seems doesn't care much

Answer (score 4):

Getters don't accept any arguments, because they are supposed to replace normal "get attribute" functionality, without brackets. So what you are need is to define a method:

```
Schema.methods.getSomething = function(what) {
    if (!what) {
        return this.somethingElse;
    } else {
        return this.something[what];
    }
};
```

and then you can simply call:

```
mySchemaObject.getSomething( "test" );
```