# How can I create virtuals for REST API in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a User model. And there is a follower relationship.

What I want is, when client requests for followers of the user, I should return the followers, and append if the follower is followed by the current user.

What is the good way to do that?

Comment: Have you found your answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at instance methods http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods as mentioned in this thread [Add arguments in a virtual getter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566817/add-arguments-in-a-virtual-getter)